# ASP.NET Identity Is default ApplicationUserManager implementing IUserEmailStore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Hello,

I was looking into ASP.NET Identity source, particulary, in [UserValidator](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140224/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserValidator.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core). I wanted to rewrite it for my own project, to be able to change error messages. So I copy that class into my project. When I try to use it - I get an error - `'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser,TKey>' does not contain a definition for 'GetEmailStore' and no extension method 'GetEmailStore' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser,TKey>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
at this line

```
var email = await Manager.GetEmailStore().GetEmailAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My question is - how can this work in AspNet.Identity framework, but not in my project? It doesn't look like that Manager is implementing `IUserEmailStore`.

All I tested, was default MVC template in VS2013

Comment: Please show us your code. At the moment it is impossible to give you a definite answer

Comment: Well, there is not much code to provide - Default ASP.NT MVC template in VS2013. Add UserValidator class (source is from that URL) and replace with it in app.IdentityConfig.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer (after searching a lot).

If you see the UserManager's source code, the `GetEmailStore()` method does exist, but is internal. Take a look:

```
    internal IUserEmailStore<TUser, TKey> GetEmailStore()
    {
        var cast = Store as IUserEmailStore<TUser, TKey>;
        if (cast == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(Resources.StoreNotIUserEmailStore);
        }
        return cast;
    }
```

So, it exists only inside files of the own Identity assembly, that's why it works there and not in your code.

Moreover, you can achieve the same result as follow:

```
var email = await Manager.GetEmailAsync(user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

[Click here to see UserManager's Source Code](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core)