# ASP.NET Identity Check email existence in custom UserValidator implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my application I created a custom version of the UserValidator so that I can configure the error messages myself.

Currently it's basically the implementation as [found here](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserValidator.cs), but with other resourcefile references.

The part I get stuck on is within the ValidateEmailAsync method.
It contains the line:

`var email = await Manager.GetEmailStore().GetEmailAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();`

This gives the error that it cannot access `GetEmailStore()` method, since it's an internal method of the `UserManager` object.
Searching for a fix for that lead me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640357/asp-net-identity-is-default-applicationusermanager-implementing-iuseremailstore/33916547), and there it's advised to use this line instead:

`var email = await Manager.GetEmailAsync(user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);`

But executing on that gives the exception that it couldn't find any user with the given Id.

Is there any other way to retrieve the email property for IUser object?
If needed, [here's my current code](https://gist.github.com/roel-de-vries/93e168fc706ba45e472214a14f716023).

Answer (score 0):

Get the user like this, then grab the email;

```
var user = await Manager.GetUserAsync(User);
var email = user.Email;
```